# A relation preventing from being an automorphism.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, vector-spaces, determinant

Someone gave me the following problem: Let $E$ be a complex vector space of dimension $n\ge 2$.

> Let $u_1,\cdots,u_r$ be $r$ endomorphisms of $E$ such that for all $k$
> $$u_k^2=-\operatorname{id},$$
> and, if $k\neq l$,
> $$u_k\circ u_l=-u_l\circ u_k.$$
> Show that $u_k$ is an automorphism for each $k$ and that $n$ must be even.

My problem with this is the following: The second relation gives that $$\det(u_k)\det(u_l)=-\det(u_l)\det(u_k),$$
hence $\det(u_k)\det(u_l)=0$ hence one of them is with determinat zero and so it can not be an automorphism, is my reasoning correct ? Thank you for your help!

Comment: The determinant of $-A$ is not the negative of the determinant of $A$ unless the space has odd dimension.

Comment: For $n\times n$ matrices $A$ we have
$$\det(-A)=(-1)^n\det A.$$ And in particular $$\det(-I_n)=(-1)^n.$$

Comment: ah so actually we have that $det(u_k)det(u_l)=(-1)^ndet(u_k)det(u_l)$

Comment: In the real case it is clear that $n$ must be even so that $(det(u_k))^2=1$ but here we are in the complex case so why $n$ can't be odd ?

Comment: $(-1)^n = -1$ for odd $n$ also holds in the complex numbers.

Comment: of course it holds! but from the relation $(det(u_k))^2=(-1)^n$ we can't say that $n$ is even because $det(u_k)$ is a complex number

Comment: You should use the second part here instead of the first. You already argued that $n$ cannot be odd in the question (without realizing that your argument assumed $n$ to be odd).

Answer (score 2):

You are given that $u_k^2=-\operatorname{id}$ where $-\operatorname{id}$ is an automorphism, so $u_k$ must be an automorphism.

You are given that $u_k\circ u_l=-u_l\circ u_k$, so if we set $n:=\dim E$ then
$$\det(u_k)\det(u_l)=\det(u_k\circ u_l)=\det(-u_l\circ u_k)=(-1)^n\det(u_l)\det(u_k),$$
where $\det(u_l)\neq0$ and $\det(u_k)\neq0$ because they are automorphisms, so $(-1)^n=1$ so $n$ is even